# Timed bash script doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following bash script, which should start some processes a few minutes after I call the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo forever start -c php /opt/leser.php -f xo.xy.xs.php | at now + 15 min
echo forever start -c php /opt/Price.php -f xo.xy.xs.php | at now + 18 min
```

The script is called `startup.sh` and I call it with

`sh startup.sh`

The reaction I get is

```
startup.sh: 2: startup.sh: at: not found
startup.sh: 3: startup.sh: at: not found
```

and I can't really understand why. The paths given are correct and forever runs globally.

Can somebody help me with what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`at` is an external command. For some reason, it is not on the PATH when it is being referred to. Your best bet would be to call it explicitly, like

```
echo forever start -c php /opt/Price.php -f xo.xy.xs.php | /usr/bin/at now + 18 min
```

On a side note: If the script has `#!/bin/bash` as its first line, you should invoke it with `bash`, not `sh.

Comment: This made it! Thank you very much!